# ExpressionTree issues

Tags: trees

I can't see what I'm doing wrong in the following - I'd like to import some XML as a `Tree` (for structure visualisation) and convert it to an Association for querying content:

```
xtree = ExpressionTree[Import["ExampleData/paintings.xml"], "XML"]
```

[image: Out1]

Which appears to work as it should.

I then use `TreeExpression` to obtain an `Association` but I get a nested list:

```
TreeExpression[xtree, "Association"]
```

Which returns this nested list and not an `Association`:

```
    {{{"Version" -> "1.0", 
   "Encoding" -> "ISO8859-1"}}, {{{"No.5, 1948"}, {"Jackson Pollock"}, {"1948"}, \
{"$140,000,000"}}, {{"Woman III"}, {"Willem de Kooning"}, {"1953"}, \
{"$137,500,000"}}, {{"Portrait of Adele Block-Bauer I"}, {"Gustav \
Klimt"}, {"1907"}, {"$135,000,000"}}, {{"Portrait of Dr. Gachet"}, \
{"Vincent van Gogh"}, {"1890"}, {"$82,500,000"}}, {{"Bal au moulin de \
la Galette, Montmartre"}, {"Pierre-Auguste Renoir"}, {"1876"}, \
{"$78,100,000"}}}, {}}
```

I've tried various options (e.g. Heads-> True makes no difference). Any suggestions?

```
$VersionNumber
14.
```

Comment: `"Association"` works only if the tree is already represented with associations, for example: `TreeExpression[Tree[Null, <|a -> Tree[1, None], b -> Tree[Null, <|c -> Tree[2, None]|>]|>], "Association"]`, which yours is not (check the `InputForm`). For general instructions regarding XML, you can read [XML Capabilities Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/XML/tutorial/Overview.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TreeExpression[ExpressionTree[expr, struct1], struct2]` does not semantically transform an expression from structure `struct1` to `struct2`, it converts `expr` to a `Tree` assuming the expression has structure `struct1` and then converts that `Tree` to an expression assuming it has structure `struct2`. These assumptions don't hold generally.  In particular, `TreeExpression[tree, "Association"]` is equivalent to `TreeFold[tree, {data, children} |-> children]`.

[`TreeFold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeFold.html) is what you want for querying a tree in a single depth-first traversal.  For example:

```
In[1]:= xtree = 
  ExpressionTree[Import["ExampleData/paintings.xml"], "XML"];

In[2]:= root = TreeExtract[xtree, 2];

In[3]:= f[{prop : "TITLE" | "ARTIST" | "YEAR" | "PRICE", {}}, {value_}] := prop -> value
f[{"SALE", {}}, rules_] := <|"SALE" -> <|rules|>|>
f[{"PAINTINGS", {}}, associations_] := <|"PAINTINGS" -> associations|>

In[6]:= TreeFold[f, root]

Out[6]= <|"PAINTINGS" -> {<|"SALE" -> <|"TITLE" -> "No.5, 1948", 
      "ARTIST" -> "Jackson Pollock", "YEAR" -> "1948", 
      "PRICE" -> "$140,000,000"|>|>, <|"SALE" -> <|"TITLE" -> 
   "Woman III", "ARTIST" -> "Willem de Kooning", "YEAR" -> "1953",
   "PRICE" -> "$137,500,000"|>|>, <|"SALE" -> <|"TITLE" -> 
       "Portrait of Adele Block-Bauer I", "ARTIST" -> "Gustav Klimt", 
      "YEAR" -> "1907", 
      "PRICE" -> "$135,000,000"|>|>, <|"SALE" -> <|"TITLE" -> 
   "Portrait of Dr. Gachet", "ARTIST" -> "Vincent van Gogh", 
  "YEAR" -> "1890", 
  "PRICE" -> "$82,500,000"|>|>, <|"SALE" -> <|"TITLE" -> 
       "Bal au moulin de la Galette, Montmartre", 
      "ARTIST" -> "Pierre-Auguste Renoir", "YEAR" -> "1876", 
      "PRICE" -> "$78,100,000"|>|>}|>

In[7]:= Dataset[%]
```

[image: Convert example paintings XML to a Dataset]

You can likely modify this example and use other [Trees](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Trees.html) functionality to query the content of the `Tree` directly without first converting to a `Dataset`, but this example shows how to convert the paintings example into associations.  Note that the `PAINTINGS` key has a list value, since  the `SALE` key is repeated.

Comment: Thanks @Ian that's s very clean and elegant (and a lot nicer than the repeated rule replacement thing I'd tried). I was trying to stay within the Trees framework but clearly need a bit more practice with it